Windows: Changes to PATH variable not detected, even after terminal restart
I've been having an issue with my Windows 11 computer that has become increasingly frustrating. Whenever I install a new CLI tool (most recently AWS CLI), it is never manually added to my PATH. Even if I edit the environment variable the PATH myself, I still get command not found errors until I restart my computer. Restarting the terminal itself is not enough. Any idea why this is happening? I'd prefer not to restart my entire system when I install something
EDIT: I found something strange. For some reason, when I open a new tab inside the Windows 11 terminal and echo %PATH% in both, the first tab shows only my system path but the second tab shows my system and user path. I've also double checked that I'm logged into the same account on both tabs using echo %USERNAME.

The user PATH might be reloaded if you log off and on again, much faster than rebooting, but not system PATH.

@DrMoishePippik I've tried this- relogging doesn't work either

Which path are you editing? There are two types, system and user. You might for example edit the local user one but the shell with the AWS CLI runs under a different account. Does the new content show up if you print the path variable to the console?

@LWChris The User path, I only have one account on my computer. And no, it doesn't show up when i print path
